# How would I rewrite this getter as a setter?

Tags: php

I have only started PHP 3 weeks ago so be gentle with me :)

I understand that the method should accept an array index and some value as parameters to use them to update the array but I have no idea of the syntax and have tried so many times now.

I'm not sure if I can still display the array inside the method?

Or should it be outside the method but inside the class?

Any help would be awesome guys.

Best,
Derek.

```
<?php
class Names{
    public $Names = array("Derek", "Paddy", "Des", "Billy" , "Jack");

    public function getElement($IndexParameter){
        return $this->Names[$IndexParameter];
    }

}

$obj = new Names;

echo $obj->getElement(4);

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to PHP coding! You're doing the right thing by asking questions, and you phrased this one very clearly, so you're doing a good job :)  Broadly speaking, it's preferable to use InitialCaps for class names, like `Names`, then camel-case for variable names and methods, e.g. `$names` and `getElements()`. You might also be interested to know that you can rewrite `array(…)` as `[…]`, e.g., `["Derek", "Paddy"]`.

Comment: This has already been answered, but still I recommend you to go to PHP Manual to solve this kind of issues. Here you have the Array section: http://ar2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php take a look at it. It's really a good manual, use it, I'll help you out a lot ;)

Comment: I have to say that I cannot see this class would be very useful. As currently you have to remember the index number in order to get data back out of this class. Something that really does not add any useful functionality.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think this is just part of a lesson/assignment, not a real-worl-problem. Just a thought.

Comment: Thank you so very much guys for the prompt answer but not just the answer also the advice that came with the answer on different aspects of my code and how I write it and the links to the manuals.Yes this was from a lesson I had to rewrite a function I previously wrote as a method to return an array element, Again thanks you PHP guys are seriously the best.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
public function setElement($IndexParameter, $NewName) {
    $this->Names[$IndexParameter] = $NewName;
}
```

Usage:

```
$obj->setElement(4, "Bilbo");
```

Note: I've kept your style, although I would generally recommend using InitialCaps for class names.

Answer (score 0):

Mark `$Names` property as `protected` or `private` to prevent direct access to it.

```
class Names{
    protected $Names = array("Derek", "Paddy", "Des", "Billy" , "Jack");

    public function getNames($IndexParameter){
        return $this->Names[$IndexParameter];
    }

    public function setNames($IndexParameter, $NewName) {
        $this->Names[$IndexParameter] = $NewName;
    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: initialising arrays using the `[]` syntax only works in PHP 5.4 or greater.

Comment: @revo I had to do that for work and replacing square brakets was a pain in the *ss. True story.

Comment: I don't know hosting providers that supports php version up to 5.3 only

Comment: Thank you so very much guys for the prompt answer but not just the answer also the advice that came with the answer on different aspects of my code and how I write it and the links to the manuals.

Comment: @revo & Roman - Chill. You both got the wrong end of the stick. **1.** I dont use old versions of PHP, unless the client gives me no option. **2.** I currently have a development environment with the latest versions of PHP 5.3/5.4/5.5/5.6 & **7.0**. But not everybody is so lucky, some have to work with older versions. And there is a lot of PHP code out there that just will not run on 7.0 without major refactoring.

Comment: RiggsFolly, Ok. If getting back to old version of array syntax will make you happy, I'll update my post. So be it. (and I won't be asking anyone to upvote my post)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Did I judge you or something?! I didn't say it about you at all. I didn't mean it that way.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I think this question is for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273677/php-error-using-new-datetime-in-php-5-3

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Thanks, I've read that post whether it was for me or not. And I continue to stand on my own position. I'll continue to use new progressive features and syntax in PHP at the same. And we used to collaborate with those companies which has its own data-centers or those hosting providers that aren't self-willed and give us the ability to adjust and control our servers by ourselves. That's the way it is!